# How do I RSpec test an association presence without recursive stack overflow errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, factory-bot

I have a Divisions model, and a Scorable model, and they are associated as below:

```
class Division < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :scoring, :as => :scorable

  validates :name, :presence => true
  validates :scoring, :presence => true
end

class Scoring < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :scorable, polymorphic: true

  validates :scorable, :presence => true
end
```

How can I test the validation on these models? If the factories for each of these contain references to each other I get a stack overflow. However, if I make factories as below, I get a Scorable can't be blank error (obviously) when I test:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :division do
    name "Division"
    organisation
    association :scoring, factory: :scoring
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :scoring do
    first 12
    second 10
    third 8
    scorable nil
  end
end
```

How can I test the presence of the association from both models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model is wrong. It's impossible to validate presence of `scoring` in `Division` model.

`Division` is on `has_one` side, there is no such field in its table. Only `Scoring` model's table will have extra fields `scorable_id` and `scorable_type`.

Remove that validation from `Division` and all of your code will be fine.

Comment: Hmm, ok. That said, I'd really like to make sure that a Division always has an associated Scoring. What's the best way to enforce this?

Comment: @kmc, there is no way. That is incorrect db schema. Check the db structure here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_one-association

Comment: Is there a better way to structure my DB then? Various models can have a Scoring attached to them (thus the polymorphism), and some of them are optional, but I absolutely want each and every Division to have a dedicated Scoring. Is creating an attached division in a callback an acceptable solution, or is there actually something wrong with my DB structure itself?

Comment: @kmc, when you create a scoring record, you need to know the scorable id and type. This means the scroable object must be saved to db at first. If your validation prevent the scorable object to be saved, you'll get nothing.

Comment: @kmc, I know your concern. In this case maybe you can try defining it in controller. For example, in a nested form with both Divising and scoring, if scoring data is absent in params, you report an error back